# How to Set up Search for Extended Web applications Sp2013

Tags: 2013, search-results

I just extended a web application to publish site in world wide web. i was able to browse the site using this new URl, everything was going fine except when i found out my search was not crawling all the contents in the extended site. In original Site everything is fine and working. Do i need to set up any other settings for extended site to provide search results.

Thank You

Comment: what is authentication type for main web app and also extended web app?

Comment: Main is in Default Zone with  Claims and Extended is in Internet Zone with claims

Comment: Claims with Windows Authentication?

Comment: No it only says Claims based Authentication, while in central admin site it says Windows

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to be noted.

1. Extending a web app does not mean you get separate content, extended web application share same content database as Default Web Application.
2. Extending Web application basically used where you want to implement different authentication to a different set of users. I.e you want claims windows on default zone and for intranet zone you want o implement ADFS.
3. When you extend a web application, you expose the same content to
   different sets of users by using an additional IIS web site to host
   the same content.
4. Search crawls only windows authentication based web application.

Now you saying not all the content crawling? what that mean...did you check the Crawl Logs for any possible error?

Check this blog for more information:
http://sharepointobservations.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/sharepoint-2013-configuring-search-to-crawl-web-applications-using-claims-and-adfs-2-0/

Comment: Thank You for you responce waqas, weird thing is crawl completes without any error or any major issues, but in search results we dont get enough results of the contents within the site. We even restarted the service and re-indexed the whole site, but nothing has changed.